# Zend Studio 9 - SVN version number doesn't show

Tags: eclipse, svn, ubuntu, zend-studio

I've installed Zend Studio 9 (Eclipse) on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, with SVN. After installing SVN I got a question about which connector I wanted to install. The server uses subversion 1.4.4, and this was not listed. I chose SVN KIT 1.3.5, for 1.5. It works in the sense that I can connect to SVN and update. I don't see any the version number of the files in Eclipse, which is essential for me.

Before I upgraded to 12.04 it worked normally, so I suppose the old svn version is not a problem. I tested with another svn-server, version 1.6, and there I have the same problem.

When using Zend Studio 8, it works normally. Still I'm wondering why it doesn't work with version 9.

Is this because I installed the wrong plugin? How can I get this working?

Comment: Subversion 1.4 is more than four years old now. Any reason not to upgrade?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not the system admin, but it worked before I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I just tested with another svn-server with 1.6 installed. Same problem.

Comment: With version 8 it works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I opened Zend Studio 8, it created another workspace. I opened a new SVN project there, and that worked correctly. Then I decided to change the workspace to the original one, with all my projects configured. No numbers. So I opened Zend Studio 9, changed workspace to the one created with 8, and it showed the numbers. So the problem is in the workspace, which I probably have to rebuild...

Comment: I think it has to do with rights. First I had the ZendStudio folder copied to /opt. When I create a workspace from there, it doesn't work. When I move it to another folder where the current user has read/write rights, it works.